# Finding eigenvector for a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider the following $3\times3$ real matrix:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1-a_1-a_2 & b_1       & c_1 \\
a_1       & 1-b_1-b_2 & c_2\\
a_2       & b_2       & 1-c_1-c_2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that
$$
I_3-A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1+a_2 & -b_1    & -c_1\\
-a_1    & b_1+b_2 & -c_2\\
-a_2    & -b_2    & c_1+c_2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so it is easy to see that $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. What is its corresponding eigenvector? If we consider a similar problem but for the $2\times2$ matrix
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1-a & b \\
a & 1-b \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then it is easy to see that $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector is
$$
\vec{v}=
\begin{pmatrix}
b \\
a \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Can this result be generalized to $3\times 3$?

Comment: Sympy: $$
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{b_{1} c_{1} + b_{1} c_{2} + b_{2} c_{1}}{a_{1} b_{2} + a_{2} b_{1} + a_{2} b_{2}}\\\frac{a_{1} c_{1} + a_{1} c_{2} + a_{2} c_{2}}{a_{1} b_{2} + a_{2} b_{1} + a_{2} b_{2}}\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks @Kurt G.